# User logins from a database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an APEX application in which I need users(students) to be able to login and view their own information. I have both the usernames and passwords stored in a table within the database I'm using.

Is there a way of using these credentials to be able to log in individually? and how would I go about doing so?

I'm very new to APEX so sorry if this is an easy question.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the [APEX documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/establishing-user-identity-through-authentication.htm#HTMDB30081) on authentication schemes.

Comment: Authentication is difficult to get right so this is not an easy question. Also: never ever store user passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that each student has to see only their own data means - I presume (as it is *about students*) that there are as many database users (schemas) as students in your class.

If that's so, presuming that each of them will use their own Apex developer and its workspace (i.e. they won't share the workspace), I believe that you'll have to create that many Apex developers and assign each developer their own schema.

That should be done connected to the internal workspace, logged in as Apex admin.

**However**, as you have to create many users *at once*, that approach might be tedious. Instead, as you already have list of users stored in a table, you could utilize `APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER` procedure and let it do the dirty job.

For example, if your table is `MY_USERS`, then such a script would do the job:

```
begin
  for cur_u in (select username, password from my_users) loop
    apex_util.create_user(p_user_name    => cur_u.username,
                          p_web_password => cur_u.password
                         );
  end loop;
end;
```

For more info, read this: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.2/AEAPI/CREATE_USER-Procedure.htm#AEAPI114

Answer (score 0):

I would use a the Custom Authentication Scheme. It is documented, so if you need help, just clicked on the "?" buttons next to the various fields.

[image: Custom Authentication Scheme]

The example code is obviously not going to work, so please do **not** copy and paste blindly. Adapt it to your situation and hopefully, you are encrypting/hashing the passwords.

That gets you started with login (authentication). Next, to the second part of your question, that students should only see "their own information" (authorization). There are no clearcut answers to this question as there are many strategies available and many issues to consider. For example, how you design your application and data schema, what database features are available to you, and regulatory compliances that you need to meet.

A great starting point to read about these "database features" can be found [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/security/virtual-private-db.html), on Real Application Security and Virtual Private Database.

The alternative includes a "poor man's implenentation of VPD" that [Martin D'Souza](https://twitter.com/martindsouza) [wrote](https://www.talkapex.com/2010/07/poor-mans-vpd-in-apex-and-oracle-xe/) about a long time back.

HTH!